ElectrumX Server Fails to Connect to bitcoind Node
What I Am Trying to Do
I am attempting to run a bitcoind regtest node and connect it to electrumx_server
The Problem
When I run electrumx_server, I encounter the following error repeatedly:
ERROR:Daemon:daemon service refused: Not Found. Retrying occasionally...
Configuration Details
ElectrumX Configuration (config):
DB_DIRECTORY = /home/omarosman23/.electrumx/db
DB_ENGINE = rocksdb
DAEMON_URL = http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@127.0.0.1:18443
COIN = BitcoinSVRegtest
NETWORK = regtest
SSL_CERTFILE = /home/omarosman23/.electrumx/electrumx.crt
SSL_KEYFILE = /home/omarosman23/.electrumx/electrumx.key

Bitcoin Daemon Configuration (bitcoin.conf):
server=1
txindex=1
rpcuser=rpcuser
rpcpassword=rpcpassword
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
[regtest]
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rpcport=18443

Expected Behavior
The electrumx_server should connect to the bitcoind node and initialize without issues
Environment Details
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
ElectrumX Version: 1.20.2
bitcoind Version: v27.0

Can you confirm if the configuration is correct for this use case, or suggest any additional debugging steps? Any help is greatly appreciated.

The problem was solved when I set rest=1 in the bitcoin.conf file
